# How to connect two Spring applications through ESB using web-service binding components?

Tags: web-services, spring, binding, esb

I have two Spring applications. One of them manages data storage (backend), the other communicates with users (frontend). Now I need to connect these two applications with ESB (Probably Fuse ESB) using web services (so probably CXF binding components). Could you explain to me how to achieve this functionality step by step?

I have Service interface and its implementation on backend Spring application.

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 0):

Any Messaging protocol (JMS, AMQP, TCP etc.) would allow you to connect two apps that run in different JVMs together. 
Have you look at [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) project? You really don't need ESB for that.

Comment: I'm afraid I do need ESB. Thats the requirement I was given